# Read a string char by char from an associative pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

**Solved**

I create a new `char *ch malloc(strlen)` and loop that string char by char. Then i copy it back using `memcpy(ch, &stringpool[index], len)` Of course, afterwards `free(ch)`.

---

I hope the title of my question is correct.

I have a stringpool

```
char **string_pool;
```

that gets initiated in a function like

```
string_pool = malloc( sizeof(char *) * 1024);
```

i get strings from stdin and scanf them into the array

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", &string_pool[index]);
```

so i can print it out using printf

```
printf("gets %s\n", &string_pool[index]);
```

how can i

- get the length of string_pool[index]
- read string_pool[index] char by char in a loop

Thank you

**Edit**

Maybe i should explain it a bit more, its a virtual machine with a virtual instruction set and a program like

```
push 1
read
gets
```

should :

- push 1 on the stack -> let x be 1
- read stdin as string into string_pool[x]
- push all characters onto the stack

the functions looks like

```
    case GETS: {
        int index = popv(); // index is already on top of the stack
        int strl = strlen(&string_pool[index]);

        printf("gets %s with a length of %d\n", &string_pool[index], strl);
        // pseudo code
        // push each char as integer on the stack
        foreach(char in string_pool[index]) push((int)char);

        break;
    }

    case READ: {  
        int index = popv();          
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &string_pool[index]);
        break;
    }

    case WRITE: {  
        int index = popv();          
        printf("%s", &string_pool[index]);
        break;
    }
```

My problem is in the GETS case. I want to push every char as int onto the stack.

Comment: What's wrong with using `strlen()`?

Comment: when i use strlen(&string_pool[i]) i get a compiler error `expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char **'`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", string_pool[index]);` will cause undefined behavior, since you have not allocated any space for string_pool[index].

Comment: Please show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It is not clear what you're up to with your edit.

Comment: What is your actual question? What is the problem you are having? The title is an instruction, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char **string_pool;
> string_pool = malloc( sizeof(char *) * 1024);
> ```

Allocates 1024 *pointers-to-char*. (`string_pool` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char*) Each of the pointers are uninitialized and point to no valid storage that can be used. Before you can use each pointer, you must make them point to valid memory by allocating memory and assigning the starting address to each pointer (so that each pointer "points" to valid memory).

To allow proper sizing and allocation for each string your read, you will either use `fgets` with a fixed buffer sufficient to store the longest input you expect, or you can use POSIX `getline` which will allocate storage for input as required. Using fgets you would do something similar to:

```
#define MAXCHR 2048
...

char buffer[MAXCHR];

fputs ("enter string: ", stdout);
if (fgets (buffer, MAXCHR, stdin) == NULL) {
    fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    return 1;
}

size_t len = strlen (buffer);   /* get the length of input (with '\n') */
if (len && buffer[len - 1] == '\n')    /* trim the '\n' from end */
    buffer[--len] = 0;          /* by overwriting with nul-character */


string_pool[index] = malloc (len + 1);      /* allocate storage for buffer */
if (string_pool[index] == NULL) {           /* validate allocation */
    perror ("maklloc-string_pool[index]");  /* handle error */
    return 1;  /* or break read loop; */
}
/* copy buffer to string_pool[index], advance index */
memcpy (string_pool[index++], buffer, len + 1);
```

You would generally do this within your read loop only allowing input while `index < 1024` to insure you did not attempt to allocate storage for one pointer too many.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I am looking for the other direction - to GET a string already stored

Comment: No problems, then you just assign the address for the already stored string to your `string_pool[index]` pointer. Since you have `1024` pointers, they can be made to point to any valid string you already have by simple assignment. (but note, following assignment, if what the pointer points to goes out of scope, then attempting to reference the string through the pointer will result in *Undefined Behavior*)

Comment: please read my edited question again. look at the case: GETS statement in the last codeblock

Comment: OK, I still think you are confusing pointers and stack storage, etc.. For instance, `scanf("%[^\n]s", &string_pool[index]);` is invalid. `string_pool[index]` is type `char*` (which corresponds to the pointer type `%[...]` requires). When you attempt to use `&string_pool[index])`, that is type `char**` and invokes undefined behavior. When you are reading with `scanf` (what I replaced with `fgets` above), you must have storage within which to store what is read. Attempting to mix assembly semantics reserving and pushing to the stack obscures the fact all strings will have the same address.

Comment: I also think you are right :P i solved it by creating a buffer of size(strlen) and copy it with memcpy, you point me the direction +1, sorry

Comment: No problem. I've managed to do that to myself more than once `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate space for each string.
So, for example,

```
string_pool[0] = malloc( 100 );
```

will then allow you to read a string that is up to 99 characters long into string_pool[0] (the extra space is needed for the terminating null).

Comment: I have to do this everytime i insert a new array? so if there are already 3 arrays, i have to do `string_pool[3] = mallog(strlen)`

Comment: Yes, you have to allocate space for each string in the array. Your original malloc only allocated space for the pointers, which remain uninitialized until you create space for each one of them.

Comment: i dont understand how this belongs to my question. I have no problem storing the strings, my problem is to read them